# passing null values to int?

Tags: c#, null, integer

Since we can not assign null value to integer type variable. So I declared `int?` type variable and used ternary operator and tried to pass the variable as parameter. But getting error.

```
int? SAP = 0;

SAP = SAP_num == null ? null :Convert.ToInt32(SAP_num);  // SAP_num is string
```

While trying to do this I am getting error, **`type of conditional expression can not be determined because there is no implicit conversion betwen '<null>' and 'int'`**

Then I tried

```
int? SAP = 0;
SAP  = Convert.ToInt32(SAP_num);
int confimation_cd = GetCode(SAP);
```

while trying to do this getting error,**`cannot convert from 'int?' to 'int'`**
**GetCode function accepts integer.**

My problem is, if the `SAP_num IS NULL` , pass as null in the function `GetCode` else pass as integer value. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

```
SAP = SAP_num == null ? (int?)null :Convert.ToInt32(SAP_num);
```

Without converting `null` to `int?`, the compiler cannot find a common type for the 2 parts of the ternary operator.

BTW it makes your code clearer to use `int.Parse` rather than `Convert.ToInt32`, since the former accepts only a string, whereas the latter can accept any fundamental type, even an Int32!

Comment: getting error while passing `SAP` to the function `GetCode(SAP);`
Please look into my second problem.

Comment: @nischalinn Make GetCode accept `int?`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension function like this:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static int? ConvertToNullableInt(this string str)
    {
        int temp;

        if (int.TryParse(str, out temp))
            return temp;

        return null;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
string SAP_num = null;
int? SAP = SAP_num.ConvertToNullableInt();
```

Comment: Please look into my second set of problem. Facing problem when passing the SAP value to the function.
`SAP = SAP_num == null ? (int?)null :Convert.ToInt32(SAP_num);` then I tried `int confimation_cd = GetCode(SAP);` `getting error cannot convert from 'int?' to 'int'`

Comment: GetCode probably accepts an int as an input parameter while you are passing a int?